# How to remap ö to return

Tags: xkb

Does one see what I am doing wrong?

```
setxkbmap -option ö:return
```

`man xkbmap` nor skimming through /usr/share/X11/xkb/ gave me any hint, While e.g. `setxkbmap -option caps:escape` works

Answer (score 1):

`setxkbmap -option` is not a generic "map this to that" mechanism.

It allows you to enable any number of *pre-defined* options that exist in your current X11 keyboard layout. Normally, a layout might have several options for the assignment of modifier keys like CapsLock, Control or AltGr, since many touch-typists prefer assigning something more useful like Control or Escape in place of CapsLock. But for a generic character like `ö`, pre-defined options are unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Added this to .xinitrc after detecting the keycode of  ö with `$ xev`

```
    # Remap ö to Return
    xmodmap -e "keycode 47 = Return"
```